# Jquery .data() not working within ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have an AJAX call which works fine and appends the returned HTML. The problem is that I am unable to attach data and I don't know why.

Everything works fine - even the marker is placed on the map - except for the data.

Here is what I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Trip/TrainCard',
    type: 'POST',
    data: modeldata,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        $(".traincards").append(data);

        var traincard = $(data).find(".traincard");
        var id = $(traincard).attr("id");
        id = id.split("_")[1];

        var icon = $(traincard).data().iconurl;

        //Create some marker options
        var markerOptions = CreateMarkerOptions(id, null, null, null, null, null, true, null, icon, map, null, place.geometry.location, null, true, null, "", null, null, ICONSCALE.TYPE.MARKER.MIDPOINT);

        //Create a marker
        var marker = CreateMarker(markerOptions, "", $(traincard).data().color);

        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        //does nothing!
        $(traincard).data({ marker: marker });

        //Add the city to the list on the map
        addNewCityToMapList(id, place.name)
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        ShowUserMessage("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
    }
});
```

For some reason, I cannot add marker to the `traincard` see `$(traincard).data({ marker: marker });`

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, `traincard` is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap it again. Now by convention, you should prefix it with $: `$traincard`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are using the `data()` method on the `data` variable which is returned, and not the elements you append from it to the DOM. Try setting the attributes you need on the returned data and then appending it to the DOM. Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    var $traincard = $data.find(".traincard");
    var id = $traincard.attr("id").split("_")[1];
    var icon = traincard.data('iconurl');
    var markerOptions = CreateMarkerOptions(id, null, null, null, null, null, true, null, icon, map, null, place.geometry.location, null, true, null, "", null, null, ICONSCALE.TYPE.MARKER.MIDPOINT);
    var marker = CreateMarker(markerOptions, "", $traincard.data('color'));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);
    $traincard.data('marker', marker)
    $data.appendTo(".traincards"); // append the element _after_ you've set its attributes

    //Add the city to the list on the map
    addNewCityToMapList(id, place.name)
},
```

Comment: You are right, but now you are appending the class `traincard` inside the `data` instead of the whole `data` like in the question.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Let said `data` is equal to `<div><i class="traincard"></i></div>`. The OP is appending the `div` while your current code is appending the `i.traincard`.

Comment: I lifted the find straight from the OPs code: `$(data).find(".traincard");` If there was a wrapping element the OP is discarding it too.

Comment: Yes, but OP first line was `$(".traincards").append(data);`